# Webpack 2 dynamic import file generated by babel

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

**Current setup**

1. Webpack with React in the setup created by `create-react-app`
2. [Babel React Intl plugin](https://github.com/yahoo/babel-plugin-react-intl) and [Manager](https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-intl-translations-manager) to extract strings for translations

**Desired behavior**

The babel plugin generates a file with all the extracted strings that has to be translated. So far, so good. This happens while webpack and babel are running (parsing and compiling the code).

I would like to `require` that generated `messages.json` file into my code, because I have to send that file to an API at runtime.

So I thought to use the Webpack 2 feature of dynamic import like so:

```
export const getTranslations = (language) => {
    import('translations/en.json').then(messages => { ... do stuff ...})
}
```

**The problem**

Webpack cannot of course find that file at compilation time, and so it complains:

`Module not found: Can't resolve 'translations/en.json'`

Answer (score 0):

if your file is in your folder (so not in node_modules) its path should be write as relative:

```
export const getTranslations = (language) => {
  import('./translations/en.json').then(messages => { ... do stuff ...})
}
```

doe this work ?

Comment: the path is not a problem since webpack is configured to resolve modules looking into node_modules but also into my src folder. It does work if I pre-generate the file. The problem is that the file is not there at build time.

Comment: @stilllife you ever get a solution for this? I'm running into this with a server-generated config file (created LONG after compile/build time)

Comment: I changed the approach and pre-generate the file on a separate babel run. So that the file is always there before compilation.